# RecyclerView won't Scroll down

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am building a notes app with kotlin, I am almost finished, I am just having this weird bug. My recyclerview is loading all of the items but I'm just not able to scroll down to them (I can see them though).
Here is my code, for the layout and the class:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/electrolize"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="@string/notes"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:queryHint="@string/search"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/search_view"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view" />



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/ColorOrangeNote"
        android:id="@+id/fabBtnCreateNote"
        android:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what could be going on without seeing the entire code, but try being more specific about the size of your recyclerView; you're asking it to measure its size (`wrap_content`) but that cannot be done until the recycler view is initialized, its adapter receives data, and all the views start to be bound (and measured) for presenting on screen. Add `bottom` constraint to it, probably to the parent. Bottom to Bottom of Parent.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini i know i was not to specific sorry about that but i will try what you said to me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not clear - are you trying to scroll items inside of RecyclerView or would like to scroll entire page to bring RecyclerView on top?

For the first option try adding   android:scrollbars="vertical"   to your RecyclerView.

For the second option you may need to put your all your views into ScrollView or something scrollable.

Comment: hey bro! ty for trying to help me! but that did not work, my problem is i have the recyclerView but the recycler does not show all the notes ,

Comment: like you can see , on the image that i add, the blue one on the blue one